String buffer gets skipped on the last loop iteration
I have a program that should print a simple histogram.
The code below is not a minimal reproducible example, as the full code is more than 100 lines, it's just the part that is necessary for understanding. If someone needs the full code to answer my question, I'll update it.
#define LINE_CHAR '#'

void printHistogram(FILE * const file, size_t const fields_size, char const * const * const names, unsigned const * const data) {
    // for all the names we are using the same buffer to avoid unnecessary heap allocations
    size_t const name_buffer_size = max_string_length(fields_size, names) + 1;
    char name_buffer[name_buffer_size];
    name_buffer[name_buffer_size - 1] = '\0';

    // same for the lines representing data
    size_t line_buffer_size = max_unsigned(fields_size, data) + 1;
    char line_buffer[line_buffer_size];
    memset(line_buffer, LINE_CHAR, line_buffer_size);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < fields_size; i++) {
        size_t current_name_length = strlen(names[i]);
        // fill the rest of the space with spaces
        memset(name_buffer + current_name_length, ' ', name_buffer_size - 1 - current_name_length);
        // copy name to buffer without null terminator
        memcpy(name_buffer, names[i], current_name_length);
        
        // prevent printing out the whole buffer, instead only print the required part
        line_buffer[data[i] + 1] = '\0';
        fprintf(file, "%s|%s\n", name_buffer, line_buffer);
        // remove this early terminator
        line_buffer[data[i] + 1] = LINE_CHAR;
    }
}

int main() {
    char const * const names[] = {"a", "b", "abc"};
    unsigned const data[] = {5, 10, 15};
    printHistogram(stdout, 3, names, data);
}

Expected:
a  |#####
b  |##########
abc|###############

Got:
a  |######
b  |###########
|################

On the last iteration the code simply skips the name buffer, why is that?

I print it two lines above for debugging purposes and it does print it here. It's literally the same buffer, that's strange

Did you run your code in a debugger? Did you verify that all your count and length variables hold the values you expect?

@Gerhardh I just did that and found out that when it did this: line_buffer[data[i] + 1] = '\0';, it went out of bounds and assigned not to the last element of line_buffer, but to the 0-th of name_buffer. As allocations on stack have reverse order, name_buffer had bigger address than line_buffer. I did not think about such a problem, because I thought it was gonna cause segfault if I tried to assign to a wrong address, turns out the stack gave me an unpleasant surprise

That's the magic of "undefined behaviour". The CPU cannot detect that you are using wrong address. Both arrays belong to your process. Therefore it is hard to detect. And generally, you should never rely on an immediate error message if you do something wrong.

There is a buffer overrun when you set the null terminator in the line_buffer array because the index used is data[i] + 1 where it should be data[i] to produce exactly that many stars.
Your approach can be simplified, taking advantage of printf formatting features:

you can pad a string output with %-*s and pass the minimum width as an int argument before the string pointer names[i].
you can limit the number of stars with %.*s and pass the maximum number of characters to output as an int argument before the line_buffer pointer.

Here is a simplified version:
#include <stdio.h>

#define LINE_CHAR '#'

void printHistogram(FILE *file, size_t fields_count, char const **names, unsigned const *data) {
    size_t max_name_length = max_string_length(fields_count, names);
    // same for the lines representing data
    size_t max_data_length = max_unsigned(fields_count, data) + 1;
    char line_buffer[max_data_length + 1];
    memset(line_buffer, LINE_CHAR, max_data_length);
    line_buffer[max_data_length] = '\0';

    for (size_t i = 0; i < fields_count; i++) {
        fprintf(file, "%-*s|%.*s\n",
                (int)max_name_length, names[i],
                (int)data[i], line_buffer);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char const *names[] = { "a", "b", "abc" };
    unsigned data[] = { 5, 10, 15 };
    printHistogram(stdout, sizeof(names) / sizeof(*names), names, data);
    return 0;
}


Is it just me or does this sound like AI? I'm not accusing you of anything, just feels kinda  similar. Chat-gpt loves to use fancy stuff like "taking advantage of ...", markdown lists, etc. Don't take this seriously, just thinking out loud

@yurich: I don't know if I should feel offended... I have been an active member for 9 years and 7 months, visited the C tag almost every day since (3234 days out of 3369) and I have always tried to express my answers using carefully crafted style in both the explanations and the code. I never use AI for this kind of work, but it is possible some of these models were trained with human contents such as mine without attribution :)

You definitely shouldn't be offended, thank you for your work

This answer is a more elaborate/better version of my answer than I had time to write up. Being a follower of the "C" tag, I appreciate the many helpful contributions from chqrlie and have absolutely no suspicions of AI being involved.

These lines:
        line_buffer[data[i] + 1] = '\0';
...
        line_buffer[data[i] + 1] = LINE_CHAR;

writes beyond the limits of the line_buffer array if data[i] is the maximal value. Notice also that the output displays one # too many in each line (I assume that is also a typo in the expected output).
The +1 should be removed:
        line_buffer[data[i]] = '\0';
...
        line_buffer[data[i]] = LINE_CHAR;

However, it should be mentioned that the code can be significantly simplified by using format specifiers in the fprintf():
    for (size_t i = 0; i < fields_size; i++) {
        fprintf(file, "%-*s|%.*s\n", max_name_size, names[i], data[i], line_buffer);
    }


Didn't know printf specifiers were a thing. Won't the specifiers cause much more allocations than needed under the hood? I think they are going to create 2 buffers on each iteration. Am I wrong?

By the way, your assumption is correct

@yurich What happens under the hood is unspecified, but I see no reason why extra allocations should be needed. However, I think it is safe to assume that fprintf() will be at least as efficient, and probably better, than the manual buffer manipulations. In any case, code simplicity is the real goal here.
